# Hibernate LazyInitializationException

Tags: java, hibernate

Tengo un problema con mi proyecto en java cuando ejecuto una función generada por el `hibernate` me la devuelve correctamente, pero si intento acceder a un objeto instancia de otra clase generada me da error porque este está `null`

La función donde salta el error es esta:

```
public List<Object> verificarUsuario(String user, String pasword) {
     List<Object> result = null;
     Usuarios us = ProveedorServicios.getUsuariosJpaController().findUsuarios(user);

     if(us != null && us.getPasword().equals(pasword)){
        int idUser = us.getIdUsuario();
        result = new ArrayList<>();
        result.add(user);
        List<Integer> roles = new ArrayList<>();
        List<RolesUsuario> rolesUsuario = findRolesUsuarioEntities();
        Iterator<RolesUsuario> iter = rolesUsuario.iterator();

        while(iter.hasNext() && roles.size() < 3){
            RolesUsuario ru = iter.next();

            if(ru.getIdUsuario().getIdUsuario() == idUser)
                roles.add(ru.getIdRol().getIdRol());
        } 

        if(!roles.isEmpty())
            result.add(roles);
        else
            result = null;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Esta es la funcion que se le asigna a:

```
Usuarios us = ProveedorServicios.getUsuariosJpaController().findUsuarios(user);

public Usuarios findUsuarios(String id) {
    Usuarios user = null;
    List<Usuarios> users = findUsuariosEntities();
    Iterator<Usuarios> iter = users.iterator();

    while(iter.hasNext() && user == null){
        Usuarios us = iter.next();

        if(us.getIdUser().equalsIgnoreCase(id))
            user = us;
    }               

    return user;        
}
```

Esta funcion la genera el hibernate findRolesUsuarioEntities() (Es la que devuelve la lista que contiene la clase que tiene entre sus atributos un objeto tipo Usuario)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles_usuario")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name = "RolesUsuario.findAll", query = "SELECT r FROM RolesUsuario r"), @NamedQuery(name = "RolesUsuario.findByIdRolesUsuario", query = "SELECT r FROM RolesUsuario r WHERE r.idRolesUsuario = :idRolesUsuario")})`
public class RolesUsuario implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id_roles_usuario")
private Integer idRolesUsuario;
@JoinColumn(name = "id_rol", referencedColumnName = "id_rol")
@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Roles idRol;
@JoinColumn(name = "id_usuario", referencedColumnName = "id_usuario")
@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Usuarios idUsuario;
```

Y esta es la excepción que me sale

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:164)
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:285)
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)
at modelo.Usuarios_$$_jvst492_a.getIdUsuario(Usuarios_$$_jvst492_a.java)
at servicios.RolesUsuarioJpaController.verificarUsuario(RolesUsuarioJpaController.java:203)
```

Comment: No entiendo por qué me pide un proxy si el se conecta sin errores a la base de datos y me devuelve la lista correctamente, el problema salta cuando intento acceder a atributos que tambien fueron generados por el hibernate

Answer (score 1):

Es el comportamiento esperado de Hibernate. La excepción `LazyInitializationException` se produce cuando intentas acceder a una relación de una entidad fuera de la transacción.

Tienes mapeada en la entidad `RolesUsuario` una relación con la entidad `Usuarios`. Con el `FetchType` configurado a `LAZY`, a menos que accedas específicamente a la propiedad idUsuario, hibernate no cargará dicha entidad en memoria (no la recuperará de base de datos, no hará el JOIN). Por tanto, cuando posteriormente quieras acceder a ella estará a `null`.

La solución más sencilla es acceder a esa propiedad en el método que se ejecute en la transacción y ya la dejarás cargada en memoria. Si siempre que accedes a `RolesUsuario` vas a necesitar acceder a `idUsuario` puedes poner el `FetchType` a `EAGER` de manera que siempre recupere esa relación.

Comment: Exacto. De esto: `@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` a esto: `@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`